# Applying width dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

How to apply a div width based on available space? I have a container (#main) and two divs within (#left and #right).

The container #main has a max-width of 1600px and #right has a width of 70%.

How do I:

(1) Calculate the actual width of #main in px?
(2) Calculate the actual width of #right in px?
(3) Subtract the width of #right from #main?
(4) Apply the result to #left?

This is more of an academic question. Yes I could simply apply css 30% to #left. But #left is fixed, #right is not and the entire #main is centred.

Comment: `css('width')` would give you the calculated value in `px`, of course it's a string (with `px` appended), you have to parse it to number. You can also use the `.width()` method.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie why do you think I need that info? I know that, and also note that I've just mentioned the use of `css('width')` as a ***getter*** (not setter).

Comment: Thanks, I will use the .width method as suggested below. Still learning here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code,
divmain - Main container
divright - Right container
divleft - Left container

```
$('#divleft').width($('#divmain').width() - $('#divright').width());
```

Comment: Does the job perfect. I'll be using this.